# How to use join and union for sub queries in mysql

Tags: mysql, join, subquery, union

im trying to use a join and union in two subqueries. Here is my query:

```
SELECT Service,SP.Second_Period, SP.TRX_SP,FP.First_Period,FP.TRX_FP
FROM (((SELECT Service, SUM(Processed) as Second_Period, COUNT(Processed) as TRX_SP
FROM pay
WHERE Status1='Processed' AND Dataime BETWEEN '2017-05-07 00:00:00' and '2017-05-14 00:00:00' 
GROUP BY Service) SP
RIGHT JOIN
(SELECT Service, SUM(Processed) as First_Period, COUNT(Processed) as TRX_FP
FROM pay
WHERE Status1='Processed' AND Dataime BETWEEN '2017-05-01 00:00:00' and '2017-05-06 00:00:00' 
GROUP BY Service) FP USING (Service))
UNION ALL
((SELECT Service, SUM(Processed) as Second_Period, COUNT(Processed) as TRX_SP
FROM pay
WHERE Status1='Processed' AND Dataime BETWEEN '2017-05-07 00:00:00' and '2017-05-14 00:00:00' 
GROUP BY Service) SP
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT Service, SUM(Processed) as First_Period, COUNT(Processed) as TRX_FP
FROM pay
WHERE Status1='Processed' AND Dataime BETWEEN '2017-05-01 00:00:00' and '2017-05-06 00:00:00' 
GROUP BY Service) FP USING (Service) ))  as tbl2
WHERE SP.Service=FP.Service
GROUP BY Service
Order BY Service
```

By doing this it return's to me this error:

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>
> near 'LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT Service, SUM(Processed) as First_Period,
>   COUNT(Processe' at line 16

What am i doing wrong? I'm using left and right join with union since i cant use Full Outer Join in mysql.

**UPDATE**

Here is the ny code by substituting Service with DAYNAME(Dataime)

```
SELECT *
FROM (
(
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT DAYNAME(Dataime), SUM(Processed) as Second_Period, COUNT(Processed) as TRX_SP
FROM pay
WHERE Status1='Processed' AND Dataime BETWEEN '2017-05-07 00:00:00' and '2017-05-14 00:00:00' 
GROUP BY DAYNAME(Dataime)) SP
RIGHT JOIN
(SELECT DAYNAME(Dataime), SUM(Processed) as First_Period, COUNT(Processed) as TRX_FP
FROM pay
WHERE Status1='Processed' AND Dataime BETWEEN '2017-05-01 00:00:00' and '2017-05-06 00:00:00' 
GROUP BY DAYNAME(Dataime)) FP USING (DAYNAME(Dataime)))
UNION ALL
(
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT DAYNAME(Dataime), SUM(Processed) as Second_Period, COUNT(Processed) as TRX_SP
FROM pay
WHERE Status1='Processed' AND Dataime BETWEEN '2017-05-07 00:00:00' and '2017-05-14 00:00:00' 
GROUP BY DAYNAME(Dataime)) SP
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT DAYNAME(Dataime), SUM(Processed) as First_Period, COUNT(Processed) as TRX_FP
FROM pay
WHERE Status1='Processed' AND Dataime BETWEEN '2017-05-01 00:00:00' and '2017-05-06 00:00:00' 
GROUP BY DAYNAME(Dataime)) FP USING (DAYNAME(Dataime)) ))  as tbl2
GROUP BY DAYNAME(Dataime)
Order BY DAYNAME(Dataime)
```

And here is the error:

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>
> near '(Dataime))) UNION ALL (

Comment: If you execute second query alone, does it work fine?

Comment: @DarshanMehta yes it'works. I have tried both of the sub queries alone and they work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a couple of changes in order for this query to work:

- Wrap inner `SELECT` queries into another `SELECT *` query to make `JOIN` work, e.g. `() SP LEFT JOIN () SP` is not a valid syntax. Instead, use `SELECT * FROM (..) SP JOIN (..) FP`
- Remove `SP.*` from outer `SELECT` as `SP` and `FP` are only visible to inner queries, use `SELECT *` instead
- Remove `WHERE SP.Service=FP.Service` from outer `WHERE` clause as again, `SP` and `FP` won't be visible.

The below query should work:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
(
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT Service, SUM(Processed) as Second_Period, COUNT(Processed) as TRX_SP
FROM pay
WHERE Status1='Processed' AND Dataime BETWEEN '2017-05-07 00:00:00' and '2017-05-14 00:00:00' 
GROUP BY Service) SP
RIGHT JOIN
(SELECT Service, SUM(Processed) as First_Period, COUNT(Processed) as TRX_FP
FROM pay
WHERE Status1='Processed' AND Dataime BETWEEN '2017-05-01 00:00:00' and '2017-05-06 00:00:00' 
GROUP BY Service) FP USING (Service))
UNION ALL
(
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT Service, SUM(Processed) as Second_Period, COUNT(Processed) as TRX_SP
FROM pay
WHERE Status1='Processed' AND Dataime BETWEEN '2017-05-07 00:00:00' and '2017-05-14 00:00:00' 
GROUP BY Service) SP
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT Service, SUM(Processed) as First_Period, COUNT(Processed) as TRX_FP
FROM pay
WHERE Status1='Processed' AND Dataime BETWEEN '2017-05-01 00:00:00' and '2017-05-06 00:00:00' 
GROUP BY Service) FP USING (Service) ))  as tbl2
GROUP BY Service
Order BY Service
```

**update**

You can't use function in `USING` clause, so you need to alias that column and use the alias in `USING`, e.g.:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
(
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT DAYNAME(Dataime) as 'day', SUM(Processed) as Second_Period, COUNT(Processed) as TRX_SP
FROM pay
WHERE Status1='Processed' AND Dataime BETWEEN '2017-05-07 00:00:00' and '2017-05-14 00:00:00' 
GROUP BY DAYNAME(Dataime)) SP
RIGHT JOIN
(SELECT DAYNAME(Dataime) as 'day', SUM(Processed) as First_Period, COUNT(Processed) as TRX_FP
FROM pay
WHERE Status1='Processed' AND Dataime BETWEEN '2017-05-01 00:00:00' and '2017-05-06 00:00:00' 
GROUP BY DAYNAME(Dataime)) FP USING(`day`))
UNION ALL
(
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT DAYNAME(Dataime) as `day`, SUM(Processed) as Second_Period, COUNT(Processed) as TRX_SP
FROM pay
WHERE Status1='Processed' AND Dataime BETWEEN '2017-05-07 00:00:00' and '2017-05-14 00:00:00' 
GROUP BY DAYNAME(Dataime)) SP
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT DAYNAME(Dataime) as `day`, SUM(Processed) as First_Period, COUNT(Processed) as TRX_FP
FROM pay
WHERE Status1='Processed' AND Dataime BETWEEN '2017-05-01 00:00:00' and '2017-05-06 00:00:00' 
GROUP BY DAYNAME(Dataime)) FP USING (`day`) ))  as tbl2
GROUP BY `day`
Order BY `day`
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works fine for service. Clearly i didn't think it would need a select all as a table but from your example i understand that it is needed to consider all as a table so to union them.  Now if i wont to substitute the service with `DAYNAME(MyDate)` so with a WEEK DAY  Name in the same query you put here it wont work. Is thar a diffrent way about the date format?

Comment: Not sure whether I understood that correctly, but if you want to add another column then you need to add it on both inner `SELECT`s and `GROUP BY`, e.g. `SELECT Service, DAYNAME(Dataime)` .... `GROUP BY Service, DATE(Dataime)`.

Comment: I have substitute  `Service` with `DAYNAME(Dataime)` here is the example `...(SELECT DAYNAME(Dataime), SUM(Processed) as Second_Period, ...GROUP BY DAYNAME(Dataime)) SP....GROUP BY DAYNAME(Dataime)
Order BY DAYNAME(Dataime)` but it wont work. It return an error in UNION ALL

Comment: You need to do that in both the queries. Can you update the question with error message?

Comment: Updated the question with the substitution and the error

Comment: It'is running but it returns to me only one row `friday` in the `day` column. The period is about 7 days of the week.

Comment: It depends a lot on available data and dates, I think you should do the grouping on `date` rather than day name. As I don't know the full context of these queries and data, it will be difficult for me to comment.

Comment: Just solve it. It was because of the `GROUP BY DAYNAME('day')` at the and since it need only `GROUP BY 'day' `. Thankyou verymuch. All the information was very precious.

Comment: Ah okay, I have updated the answer. Thanks for your inputs :)

Comment: i'm back asking about an issue that i'm having with this query. If i execute the query and for example for Monday i have records only for the second period and not for the first period it shows me the values of Monday on the first period column and the second period column as null. what can cause it?

Comment: I guess `UNION` might suppress the records if both have the same value. If you are querying for one day only then you don't need to use two queries. One should suffice..

Comment: Im querying for two periods. Like i'm comparing two weeks or two months or two periods each by ten days

Comment: Sorry, still struggling to understand. Can you add an example please?

Comment: here is an example. I want to compare the number of the transactions based on a week day. It means, given two different periods(two different weeks for example) i want to now how many transactions did i have on Tuesday for the first week and how many on Tuesday for the second week. Now with the query that i'm using, if i don't have transactions on Tuesday of the first week it shows me the transactions of the second week on the first and shows null at the second week. I hope the example would make it easier to understand what i mean